# dynamic class binding in nuxtjs/vuejs with tailwind classes

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, tailwind-css, nuxtjs

I am assigning css classes according to some timer to a div.

> s0 can be 0 - 5

this assignment (as below) works fine but it feels like it is a lot of overhead in both writing and performance. Is there another way to assign css classes dynamically in nuxt?

e.g. writing `class="-mt-{s0*8}"` directly on the template? Why is there a need for a boolean to return? Am I missing something?

```
  <template> 
    <div class="secs-0" :class='{"-mt-8": oct(s0, 8),
                                      "-mt-16": oct(s0, 16),
                                      "-mt-24": oct(s0, 24),
                                      "-mt-32": oct(s0, 32),
                                      "-mt-40": oct(s0, 40)}'>

...



<script>
    ...
    methods: {
         oct(o, p) {
          return o*8 == p
         }
    },
    ...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I needed to look at Class and Style Bindings at vuejs.org, not nuxtjs.org (where I found nothing :-)

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html

The proper way to do this, is to use the array syntax "['']" with string concatenation as @tao showed in the comments

```
 <template> 
    <div class="secs-0" :class="['-mt-'+h0*8]">
```

@tao also made a proper jsfiddle, thank you!

https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/f5zdstex/

Comment: You'll probably find this syntax handy in your case: `:class="['-mt-' + s0 * 8]"`

Comment: Here's a [tiny toy](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/f5zdstex/).